# PouchDb dynamic headers

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I'm trying to find a way to add headers dynamically. Our authentication scheme requires headers adjustment periodically. 
How to replace the expired token dynamically?

```js
let db = new PouchDB('MyLocalDb');
let remoteUrl = new PouchDB(remoteUrl, { headers: { authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.getToken() });
db.replicate.to(remoteUrl, {live: true});
```